# Root test for series: the series diverges a lot faster when $L$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

The Root Test given in my university textbook is as follows :

Let $\displaystyle L = \limsup_{n \to ∞} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. If $L<1$ then the series is convergent. If $L>1$ then the series is divergent. If $L=1$ then the test fails. Above is the background info. However, I would like to discuss further on the distinction between

- case 1: $1<L<+∞$ and
- case 2: $L=+∞$.

Although the series diverge in both cases, they seem quite different for me, as one grows significantly faster than the other. Is there a way to make use of this distinction?

Possible trains of thoughts:

1.take the sequence of partial sums and form a series out of this sequence

2.use the sequence of partial sums as the coefficients of a power series.

Comment: $L=\infty >1$ is part of the second case.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear. I just edited my question.

Comment: If $L = \infty$ then the sequence $\sqrt[n]{|a_n |}$ is not bounded. Otherwise, the sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the three cases, let's focus on the proof of the root test.

$\displaystyle L=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ implies there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ such that

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{n_k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{|a_{n_k}|}=L\in [0,\infty]$.
2. If $L<\infty$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$, such that for every $n>N$, $\displaystyle \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}<L+\varepsilon$.

If $L<1$, then by 2. we know that $|a_n|<(L+\varepsilon)^n$ for sufficiently large $n\ge N$ and we can take $\varepsilon$ so that $L+\varepsilon<1$. Then $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty|a_n|<\sum_{n=N}^\infty (L+\varepsilon)^n<\infty,\quad \text{since}\ (L+\varepsilon)<1.$$

If $1<L<\infty$, then there by 1. we know that $|a_{n_k}|>(L-\varepsilon)^{n_k}$ for some $n_k$ sufficiently large, where $\varepsilon$ is taken so that $L-\epsilon>1$. Since $a_{n_k}$ doesn't converge to $0$, then of course $\{a_n\}$ diverges.

Now can you write down the proof for $L=\infty$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your proof of the root test! I know that the series diverges in both cases, but I want to discuss how much faster the series diverges when L is infinite rather than finite.

Comment: @XYSquared As you can see from the proof, the divergence part follows from the terms do not go to zero as $n$ tends to infinity which is very rough. Since as you know, there are lots of convergent sequences yet with their terms go to zero. Cauchy's convergence test may not be the best tool comparing how fast they diverge. In order to study how fast they diverge, I think you have to compare them with some known divergent series, like harmonic series. For example, maybe you can take a look at this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html